# Selenium wb driver: Verify text passes when the text is cut off?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Snippet of my verifyText function:

```
String actual = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).getText();
String expected=data;
```

Snippet of my isDisplayed function:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).isDisplayed()){
```

The data = "Please enter a valid email address"

However, the only text visible is "Please".  But when I use the Selenium IDE, it too see's "Please enter a valid email address".  It is just being cut off.  But the automation passes this step, but I would like it to fail.  I tried the two functions above, same results.

Is there a way I can get this step to fail when expecting "Please enter a valid email address" but only "Please" is visible to a user?

HTML:

```
<li class="mktFormReq mktField" title="Please enter a valid email address">
<label>Email Address:</label>
<span class="mktInput mktError">
<input id="Email" class="mktFormText mktFormEmail mktFReq" type="text" tabindex="3"     maxlength="255" value="" name="Email">
<span class="mktFormMsg" style="left: 214px;">Please enter a valid email address</span>
</span>    
</li>
```

Visually:

Only Please is visible, the rest if cut off.

Comment: Share your HTML also and we can then try to figure out why it does what it does.

Comment: Added HTML above, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium doesn't know what you see on the page, it only checks the HTML. Your HTML contains "Please enter a valid email address", and I don't know why it doesn't show up in your page.

Since it will always return what it is in HTML, your test will always fail if you just check for "Please".

Comment: I understand both comments, and certainly agree automation will always have its limits.  I was just curious to see if any workaround (even out of the box) solution existed.  Of course on a verifyText basis, the automation will pass the whole sentence because it does in fact exist.

Answer (score 0):

The node contains the text "Please enter a valid email address", that's why selenium is passing, does not matters if it is visible or not (In fact, it is visible, because the element is present)

I think there is no way to validate that in this case, you just need to check that visually.

Remember, Automation is not manual test substitute.